# What is the most simple way to check if a string may convert to AnsiString safely in XE4 and above?

Tags: delphi, unicode

In Delphi XE4 and above, we may write something like:

```
function TestAnsiCompatible(const aStr: string): Boolean;
begin
end;
```

`string` in Delphi XE4 is declared as `UnicodeString`.  It may hold a unicode string.

If we do some type conversion:

```
function TestAnsiCompatible(const aStr: string): Boolean;
var a: AnsiString;
begin
  a := aStr;
  Result := a = aStr;
end;
```

Some compiler warnings should prompt:

```
[dcc32 Warning]: W1058 Implicit string cast with potential data loss from 'string' to 'AnsiString'
[dcc32 Warning]: W1057 Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string'
```

Is there a much simple and neat way to test if `aStr` is fully compatible with AnsiString?  Or we shall check character by characters:

```
function TestAnsiCompatible(const aStr: string): Boolean;
var C: Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  for C in aStr do begin
    if C > #127 then begin
      Result := False;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I was hoping in the [`IsTextUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx) function with [`IS_TEXT_UNICODE_ASCII16`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672(v=vs.85).aspx#IS_TEXT_UNICODE_ASCII16) flag. No luck with it.

Comment: The 'character by character' function is not solving the question asked but doing a different thing.

Comment: Can you explain why you think #256 is special?

Comment: I thought characters not in range of #0..#255 are AnsiChar?  XE shall convert those characters to `?` if cast to AnsiString.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang - keep in mind the meaning of AnsiChar values outside the ASCII range (i.e., >= #128) is codepage-dependant. This implies that the same UnicodeString may convert without loss to an AnsiString with (say) the 'Latin-1' codepage set but convert with loss to an AnsiString with the Greek codepage set.

Comment: Perhaps I shall perform checking on range #0 to #127 only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is type-cast away the warnings:

```
function TestAnsiCompatible(const aStr: string): Boolean;
var
  a: AnsiString;
begin
  a := AnsiString(aStr);
  Result := String(a) = aStr;
end;
```

Which can be simplified to this:

```
function TestAnsiCompatible(const aStr: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := String(AnsiString(aStr)) = aStr;
end;
```

Comment: Using string comparison works but it seems like an expensive calculation.  But I think this is the only solution so far.

Comment: If you want to ensure the Ansi data will roundtrip back to Unicode without any loss, then yes.  An actual conversion is needed.  Otherwise, if you just want to know whether the conversion to Ansi would be lossy, try calling [`LocaleCharsFromUnicode()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.LocaleCharsFromUnicode) or [`WideCharToMultiByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130.aspx), specifying the `WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS` flag and then check the output of the `UsedDefaultChar` parameter.

Comment: Does the compiler never optimize String(AnsiString(<string-type>) to just <string-type>?

Comment: @David: no, I don't think so. I think this explicit cast will not be optimized away, exactly to make code like the above possible.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: no, it is not optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

I used to check if `String(a) = AnsiString(a)`, until I had a user who had transferred data from one PC to another, and that had a different codepage. Then the data could not be read back properly. Then I changed my definition of "safe" to "string is code page 1252" (as this is the region where most of my users are). Then when reading back my data, I know I have to convert the string back from code page 1252.

```
function StringIs1252(const S: UnicodeString): Boolean;
// returns True if a string is in codepage 1252 (Western European (Windows))
// Cyrillic is 1251
const
  WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS = $00000400;
var
  UsedDefaultChar: BOOL;   // not Boolean!!
  Len: Integer;
begin
  if Length(S) = 0 then
    Exit(True);
  UsedDefaultChar := False;
  Len := WideCharToMultiByte(1252, WC_NO_BEST_FIT_CHARS, PWideChar(S), Length(S), nil, 0, nil, @UsedDefaultChar);
  if Len <> 0 then
    Result := not UsedDefaultchar
  else
    Result := False;
end;
```

But if you want to check if your string can safely be converted to ansi - completely independent of the code page that is used when writing or reading, then you should check if all characters are in the range from #0..#127.

Comment: #0..#127 is 7bit ASCII, which is represented by codepage 20127, so you could use the same code above to handle that.